# How to do subtraction with sets in which the elements have multiplicity indicators?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to do subtraction with sets `l1` and `l2`, which contain multiplicity indicators. For example,

```
 l1 = {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}};
 l2 = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
 subset[l1, l2]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {3, 4}}
> ```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Pardon me, why is `{3,4}` in the subset list?

Comment: Do you know about `Intersection` and `Complement`? `Intersection[l1, l2] == {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}` and `Complement[l1, l2] == {{3, 4}}`

Comment: Per definition a *set* is a collection of **distinct** objects. Therefore, the double `{1,1}` in `l1` is not OK. Otherwise, the solution to your question would be `Complement[l1, l2]`.

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about [multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).  Well, that seems to be andre's interpretation, too.  If so, the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: concerning the ordering, what sould be the result if `l1={{1,2}}`and `l2={{2,1}}`, {{1,2}} or {} ?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/8115/

Comment: Based on the way this question has been interpreted I am closing it as a duplicate.  If anyone feels this is inaccurate flag the post for my attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l1={{1,1},{1,1},{2,2},{3,4}};
l2={{1,1},{2,2}};
```

You want to obtain :

```
Subset[l1,l2]={{1,1},{3,4}}
```

that is to say :

- remove elements of l1 which are in l2.
- If l1 has identical elements "elt1" you want the multiplicity of the removals to correspond to the multiplicity of "elt1" in l2.

This can be done with :

```
Fold[#1 /. {start___, #2, end___} :> {start, end} &, l1, l2]
```

> {{1, 1}, {3, 4}}

The original order of l1 is preserved.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fairly fast subtract-by-multiplicity.

```
deleteByMultiplicity[s1_, s2_] := Module[
  {val, news2, h1},
  news2 = Tally[s2];
  Do[val[news2[[j, 1]]] = news2[[j, 2]], {j, Length[news2]}];
  Reap[Do[
     h1 = val[s1[[j]]];
     If[IntegerQ[h1] && h1 > 0, val[s1[[j]]] -= 1, Sow[s1[[j]]]]
     , {j, Length[s1]}]][[2, 1]]
  ]
```

Examples:

```
n = 4;
s1 = RandomInteger[100, {10^n, 2}];
s2 = RandomInteger[100, {Ceiling[10^n/2], 2}];

Timing[d1 = deleteByMultiplicity[s1, s2];]

(* Out[417]= {0.080000, Null} *)
Length[d1]

(* Out[413]= 7289 *)

n = 5;
s1 = RandomInteger[100, {10^n, 2}];
s2 = RandomInteger[100, {Ceiling[10^n/2], 2}];

Timing[d1 = deleteByMultiplicity[s1, s2];]

(* Out[422]= {0.660000, Null} *)

Length[d1]

(* Out[423]= 51692 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach using `Reap` and `Sow` (where f is used just a wrapper):

```
fun[a_,b_]:=Join @@ (Table[#[[1]], {#[[2]]}] & /@ (Cases[
   Last@Reap[
     Join[Sow[1, f[#]] & /@a, 
      Sow[-1, f[#]] & /@ b], _, {#1 /. f[x_] :> x, Total@#2} &], 
   Except[{_, 0}]]))
```

`fun[l1,l2]` yields the desired:

{{1, 1}, {3, 4}}

Some other tests (just to be clear about what subtraction is desired):

```
fun[{{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 
   2}}]
```

yields:

{{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {3, 4}}

If the second list contains elements that are not in the first list then the condition for the cases needs to be modified to `Except[{_,_(?#<=0&)]`.